# How to apply coupon code to cart in graphql?

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, graphql, magento-graphql

Now I'm trying to apply a coupon to the cart and I followed this link: **[applyCouponToCart mutation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/apply-coupon.html)**

**But we don't get the mask id when customer is  logged in, so how to get mask id for logged in customer. Otherwise what is other option for logged in customer ?**

Comment: As per this documentation https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/masked-id-fro-cart-id-magento-2/ the mask id will only be available for guest users.

Comment: yes i have checked that link but i now i got mask id using by graphql query for logged in customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has provided get customer cart id(mask id). So if you want to get current customer mask id run below query and check.

```
{
  customerCart {
    id
  }
}
```

And also pass in header customer token.

```
{
   "Authorization": "Bearer zcnj8wd03u19s5fw1yvkprs23du7tfkh"
}
```

Let me know if any query.

**`Updated`**

Also we face same issue some time as you are facing. For this you need to login into magento side in same browser tab. So, your GraphQl query will found current user data.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hello @mohit, i have got the cart id, but after i send request to "applyCouponToCart mutation" it's throw error "The current user cannot perform operations on cart". any help in this ?

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32785

Comment: It's not working in 2.4.3 version.

Comment: Can you check my Updated answer

Comment: Yes, i have checked your answer and it's working for me.